# How to translate or override standard text strings in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

The most standard APEX components have some text on them. What I need to do is to **translate** or **override** those labels to my native language.

Text which I need to replace:

- Error messages (inline notification message, error page and error popup when validation failed)
- Labels on standard buttons (for exapmle there're buttons `OK` and `Cancel` when you fire `apex.confirm` javascript method).
- Labels in actions menus, search bars and so on, which you can see on different reports.
- `Filter..` label which you can see when click on a report column.
- Different notifications.

Maybe I forgot something. In general, I need to know, how I can override standard text string and where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of these (though perhaps not all) should be covered by [Internal Messages Requiring Translation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/translating-messages.htm#GUID-1007B380-42DB-4D0E-857D-A112EA7BCDAF) - e.g. from your specific examples:

```
APEX.IG.FILTER_WITH_DOTS        Filter...
APEX.NUMBER_FIELD.VALUE_INVALID #LABEL# must be Numeric.
APEX.DIALOG.OK                  OK
```

There is [a website](http://translate-apex.com/apex/f?p=800:START::::::) to help you with translating these into languages other than the 10 that APEX already supports.